# graph regression detection in neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I've had a graph with such dimensions

```
75 millions of nodes
238 millions of relationships
```

for several years.

I regenerate it periodically from external data (by importing csv).

Then I do batches of **allshortestpaths** searches, single search take several milliseconds. But whole batch of 100k searches usually took 5-10 minutes.

Some time ago batch searches became several times slower - always 30++ minutes.

Are there any tools to investigate the problem? I use cypher and java driver, there were no neo4j updates at that time (now 4.0.11)

I tried beefier server with Oracle linux instead of Debian, and neo4j 4.2.4 instead of 4.0.11, but that didn't help. So, the problem is probably inside the graph.

I've set logging for slow searches, but there are no searches slower than dozens of milliseconds. Unfortunatelly, I cannot revert to old (faster) graph to measure mean time.

UPDATE:

Old search

```
MATCH (one:Obj{oid:'id1'}) with one MATCH (two:Obj{oid:'anyOf100kId'}), path=allshortestPaths((one) -[*0..4]-(two)) WHERE ALL (x IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) WHERE x.val<130) return path limit 100;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Plan      | Statement   | Version      | Planner | Runtime       | Time | DbHits | Rows | Memory (Bytes) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "PROFILE" | "READ_ONLY" | "CYPHER 4.2" | "COST"  | "INTERPRETED" | 44   | 82495  | 7    | 7707104        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------+------------------------+
| Operator                   | Details                                                                                         | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Memory (Bytes) | Page Cache Hits/Misses |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------+------------------------+
| +ProduceResults@graph.db   | path                                                                                            |              1 |    7 |     224 |                |                    0/0 |
| |                          +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------+------------------------+
| +Limit@graph.db            | 100                                                                                             |              1 |    7 |       0 |                |                    0/0 |
| |                          +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------+------------------------+
| +ShortestPath@graph.db     | path = (one)-[anon_112*0..4]-(two) WHERE all(x IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) WHERE x.val < $autoint_2) |              1 |    7 |   82267 |        7707104 |                    0/0 |
| |                          +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------+------------------------+
| +CartesianProduct@graph.db |                                                                                                 |              1 |    1 |       0 |                |                    0/0 |
| |\                         +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------+------------------------+
| | +NodeIndexSeek@graph.db  | two:Obj(oid) WHERE oid = $autostring_1                                                          |              1 |    1 |       2 |                |                    0/0 |
| |                          +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------+------------------------+
| +NodeIndexSeek@graph.db    | one:Obj(oid) WHERE oid = $autostring_0                                                          |              1 |    1 |       2 |                |                    0/0 |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------+---------+----------------+------------------------+

7 rows available after 0 ms, consumed after another 44 ms
```

Now I've switched to parameters + UNWIND, but see no difference.

In java List I put 100k ids, then

```
final String qu = "MATCH (one:Obj {oid: 'id1' }) WITH one UNWIND $batch AS row MATCH (two:Obj {oid:row}), path=allshortestPaths((one) -[*0..4]-(two)) WHERE ALL (x IN RELATIONSHIPS(path) WHERE x.val<130) return path limit 10000";

Result r = session.run(qu, parameters("batch", orgs));
```

Search didn't stop even after 30 minutes. Also separate searches are better, because I can break the loop and at least process partial results.

So, any ideas? 1 month ago it worked much faster.

Comment: Since it is able to finish, PROFILE the query, and add the expanded query plan to your question.

Comment: (posted PROFILE) Thanks for your time. Unfortunatelly, I cannot benchmark old (fast) graph. Maybe these pairs were "slow" from the beginning. Now in every "slow" batch I have only 0-4 slow checks, but still they finish in quite impressive 5-40 milliseconds. I'm afraid something happened with AVERAGE speed of all queries, but not with couple of slowest

Comment: The plan was for a single pairing. How were you running this on all (or a subset) of pairs? Were you doing all that in Cypher (two MATCHes or a single MATCH pattern to capture all combinations of 2) or were you calling the query per pairing from your client?

Comment: I run 100k requests from java application to find all paths between node1 and any of 100k nodes. These 100k are not connected.

Comment: 100k queries like this won't perform well. Instead try to handle it all with one query, try passing in the 100k nodes (or means to look them up) via parameters as a list. UNWIND the list, then perform your matches. Read this article for reference: https://dzone.com/articles/tips-for-fast-batch-updates-of-graph-structures-wi

Comment: What do you mean by 'regenerate' the graph? delete all or create a new DB?

Comment: Well, it didn't help at all. 1 month ago it was quite fast without parameters. I updated my question

Comment: I recreate graph from csv weekly, because source data changes a lot. So I cannot track changes.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer: I didn't find/create a tool to detect large clusters of nodes. The problem was solved by adding more RAM to fit all 64GB of data.

Also, spent couple of days trying to boost performance even more, but failed.
Different JVM settings almost do nothing (large heap, large pagecache).
Community edition seems to be hard-limited to 10 cores, but effective limit is even lower, because difference between 4 and 10-20 core mode is just several percent.